# Why can I not install Ubuntu on my Alienware M13?

Tags: 14.04, boot

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Alienware M13 Laptop.  I've tried several steps that I've been able to find through Google searches.  My issue seems to be random.  I can sometimes get into Ubuntu, login, then the system will just freeze up and not allow me to do anything.  Then I will stumble across the issue when booting that says graphics could not be configured properly and they system is running in low graphics mode.  I try to boot into safemode after this and can not even do that.  Any help would be greatly apprechiated.

Comment: do you have a graphics card? which one?

Comment: sorry nothing to go on. I would try to find out if there is an error somewhere. "low graphics mode" is GPU related (so pick the nomodeset from the boot up properties in grub to see if that fixes it). Also: make sure all hardware is Linux compatible. Maybe your GPU is too new for 14.04. And yes: use 15.10 It might have a slightly better hardware list.

Comment: I've just tried to install 15.10 and the system is just rebooting after I select install.  I can not try before installation either.  The machine just reboots.  I'm in UEFI.  What should I try to do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have nvidia graphics card try what Rinzwind says in the comment and after that
In the terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T to open it or Ctrl+Alt+F1) run this

```
 sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
 sudo reboot
```

This will remove any installed nvidia drivers.

Then install the new drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

In case if you are not seeing the side bar try this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: I've successfully done this, now I can not see the menu bar at the top or the icons on the left hand side.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @DylanMitchell. try the just edited answer '...dconf reset ...compiz'

Comment: This has seemed to work!  Thank you so much.  I was also having issues with the  machine locking up before I had the correct nvidia drivers installed, will report back if I'm having any issue with system lock up again.  Thanks again!

Comment: @DylanMitchell. Glad to know it worked.If you are okay with the solution, accept it as solution by using the tick mark against it.